# Как лучше реализовать список enums в MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, hibernate, jdbc

у меня есть фильмы у которых есть жанры в виде ENUM. Жанров у фильма естественно может быть несколько.
Как лучше это реализовать в MySQL ?

Сейчас это у меня выглядит так -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если жанров может быть несколько, нужен SET, а не ENUM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вполне ясно, что вы имеете в виду под *"Как лучше это реализовать в MySQL"* и к чему тут теги java и hibernate.

Но я бы рекомендовал вам поступить следующим образом. Таблицу `Movies` оставьте такой, какая она у вас есть. Таблицу `Genres` мы сгенерируем вот так:

```
CREATE TABLE genres
(
    film_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    genre   VARCHAR,
    CONSTRAINT film_genre_idx UNIQUE (film_id, genre),
    FOREIGN KEY (film_id) REFERENCES films (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Таким образом, если у вас будет несколько фильмов, то все их жанры будут храниться в этой одной таблице. Даже если у одного фильма будет более двух жанров, то это будет нормально работать в такой таблице. Теперь перейдём к сущности **Movie** *(вы ведь не просто так ставили теги java и hibernate?)*. Я покажу вам только то, как аннотировать поле `genres` в **Movie**, саму сущность я, думаю, вы уже написали:

```
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "genres", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "film_id"))
    @Column(name = "genre")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Genre> genres;
```

Насколько вы видите, тут у нас Set, чтобы вы могли к одному фильму привязать несколько жанров. Аннотация `CollectionTable` указывает, в какой таблице должно храниться содержимое нашего множества. В аннотацию `Enumerated` я поставил `EnumType.STRING`, что позволит элементам ENUM сохраняться в таблицу как строковое значение. Ещё я установил `FetchType.EAGER`, чтобы при вытаскивании **Movie** из базы, множество genres было бы проинициализировано и заполнено соответствующими значениями.

В результате записи в таблице `genres` будут иметь примерно такой вид:

```
film_id      genre
-------      -----
100001       HORROR
100001       THRILLER
100002       HORROR
100003       THRILLER
```

Видите? У фильма с id 100001 два жанра: **HORROR** и **THRILLER**

Comment: Добрый день. Во первых, хочу поблагодарить за развёрнутый ответ. Он мне очень помог. Но осталось пару вопросов: 1) Как создавать критерии запросов в таком случае ?  Допустим если мне нужно вывести все фильмы включающие определенный жанр ? Пример запроса- https://postimg.cc/z3LCN37K , enum - https://postimg.cc/4nSTK2pj. 2) Я так понимаю, что для каждого фильма в таблице genres создаются новые строки с названиями жанров, что занимает память, верно ? Если так, можно ли этого как-то избежать ?

Comment: @SnejOK Вообще, лучше всего этот вопрос задать отдельно и оформить как отдельный вопрос. 1) У вас вроде есть запрос. Только вы SELECT забыли написать в начале ну и мелочи всякие подправить. Но общая идея верна. 2) Если это вас смущает, то можно использоваться отношения ManyToMany, но каждое отношение там будет тоже оформлено как отдельная строка. Я лично решения этой проблемы не знаю (если это для вас проблема). Лучше обратить к специалистам по БД, коим я не являюсь. Оформите свой вопрос как новый вопрос, и вам ответят.

Comment: @SnejOK по поводу второго пункта - а как вы кстати иначе хотите? Иначе по-моему никак и не получится. Если вы для каждого фильма будете создавать новые записи (то есть как сейчас), то у вас будут множится записи. Отношением ManyToMany у вас тоже будут множится записи. Они будут множиться у вас в любом случае - как вы иначе себе это представляете? Другое дело, если бы у вас было по одному жанру в каждом фильме, но это не так

Comment: @SnejOK ещё я слышал о таком, что массивы можно хранить в одной ячейке... Но это по-моему костыль. И да, вопрос с памятью это не решит. Короче, не парились бы вы лучше из-за пары лишних мегабайт. Ну будет у вас на сайте 1000000 фильмов - сами посчитайте, сколько лишней памяти из-за этого потребуется. А именно - почти нисколько

Comment: Пожалуй, последую вашему совету. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Таблица `Genre` с колонкой `id` и какими нужно другими колонками (название и т.п.). Одна строка - один enum.
Таблица `MovieGenre` с колонкой `id` и колонками `move_id`, `genre_id`, которые ссылаются на `id` в `Movie` и `Genre`, соответственно.